# How to visually identify the viewbox of a SVG with CSS?

Tags: css, svg, viewbox

I'm willing to visually identify the `viewbox` of a SVG in order to avoid any element going out of it.

This is what I felt was the most intuitive way to do it in CSS ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghezh5z0/)):

```
polygon{
    stroke:red;
    stroke-width:20px;
}

svg{
    stroke:blue;
    stroke-width:20px;
}
```

I was expecting the same behavior of the `<svg>` element than any other; i.e. I was expecting to have a 20px wide blue stroke around my `<svg>` element, as it's the case for my `<polygon>` element but my expectations were obviously over optimistic.

I'd like a direct interaction with CSS -- i.e., without having to programmatically create a `<rect>` element with the coordinates and positions of the `viewbox`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the root `svg` you can simply use regular CSS styling, as opposed to `stroke` etc:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghezh5z0/1/)

Change

```
svg{
    stroke:blue;
    stroke-width:20px;
}
```

To

```
svg{
    border:20px solid blue;
}
```